# Using JList with Ordered Array Lists

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, arraylist, jlist

I'm having quite a bit of trouble getting the elements inside my list to get displayed onto my GUI's JList. I tried addElement and some other styles of JList methods that come with JDK and I couldn't get any to work the way I wanted.

I'm trying to display input strings on the JList and then store them in my separate list to call upon. Is there a preferred methodology when working with JList and JFrame this way?

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class PlaylistMakerFinal extends JFrame implements ActionListener{

private static int SIZE = 1000;
private static int WIDTH = 600;
private static int HEIGHT = 600;
OrderedArrayList<String> songList = new OrderedArrayList<String>(SIZE);
{
    songList = new OrderedArrayList<String>();
}

private JButton deleteButton;
private JButton addButton;
private JTextField addTextField;
private JTextField searchTextField;
private JButton searchButton;
private JButton exitButton;
private JList<String> songArea;


public void displayText(){
    this.getContentPane().add(songArea);

    }

public PlaylistMakerFinal() {



    setTitle("Playlist Maker");
    Container pane = getContentPane();
    pane.setLayout(null);
    setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);

    songArea = new JList<String>();

    addTextField = new JTextField();

    searchTextField = new JTextField();

    exitButton = new JButton("Exit");
    exitButton.addActionListener(this);

    addButton = new JButton("Add");
    addButton.addActionListener(this);

    deleteButton = new JButton("Delete");
    deleteButton.addActionListener(this);

    searchButton = new JButton("Search");
    searchButton.addActionListener(this);


    songArea.setSize(250, 400);
    addTextField.setSize(250, 30);
    searchTextField.setSize(250, 30);
    addButton.setSize(100, 40);
    deleteButton.setSize(100, 40);
    searchButton.setSize(100, 40);
    exitButton.setSize(100, 40);

    songArea.setLocation(10, 50);
    addTextField.setLocation(10,10);
    searchTextField.setLocation(10, 480);
    addButton.setLocation(300, 5);
    deleteButton.setLocation(420, 5);
    searchButton.setLocation(300, 475);
    exitButton.setLocation(420, 475);

    pane.add(songArea);
    pane.add(addTextField);
    pane.add(searchTextField);
    pane.add(addButton);
    pane.add(deleteButton);
    pane.add(searchButton);
    pane.add(exitButton);
    setVisible(true);

}

public static void main(String args[]){
    PlaylistMakerFinal playlist = new PlaylistMakerFinal();

}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
    JList songArea = new JList(songList.list);
    String action = e.getActionCommand();
    String addTitle;
    String deleteTitle;
    String searchTitle;
    int searchInt;
    int deleteInt;

//        Just some methods I was testing that didn't bear any fruit.
//        DefaultListModel<String> listModel;
//        listModel = new DefaultListModel<String>();
//        JList songArea = new JList(listModel);

    //Method to add a song to the list
    if(action.equals("Add")){

        addTitle = addTextField.getText();
        System.out.println("ADDED " + addTitle);

                songList.insertEnd(addTitle);
                songArea.setListData(songList.list);
//                  songArea.addElement();
    }

    //Method to remove a song from the list
    else if(action.equals("Delete")){

        deleteTitle = addTextField.getText();

    deleteInt = songList.seqSearch(deleteTitle);

    if(deleteInt != -1){
        songList.removeAt(deleteInt);
        songArea.remove(deleteInt);
        System.out.println("DELETED " + deleteTitle);
        }

    }

    //Method to search the list for a song and return an answer in a JOptionPane
    else if(action.equals("Search")){
        searchTitle = searchTextField.getText();
        searchInt = songList.seqSearch(searchTitle);

        songArea.setSelectedIndex(searchInt);

    }
    //Method to exit the program and close the window
    else if(action.equals("Exit")){
        System.exit(0);
    }
    else{

    }
}
```

ArrayListADT:

```
}

// Generic ArrayList interface, defining all the methods an array list should have.
// Any class that implements this interface must define all the below methods,
// or just declare them as abstract.

public interface ArrayListADT<T> extends Cloneable
{
// Determine whether or not the list is empty.
public boolean isEmpty();

// Determine whether or not the list if full.
public boolean isFull();

// Return the number of elements in the list.
public int listSize();

// Return the maximum size of the list.
public int maxListSize();

// Output the elements of the list.
public void print();

// Returns a copy of objects' data in store.  
// This method clones only the references stored in the list.
// The objects themselves are not cloned.
public Object clone();

// Determine whether item is the same as the item in the list
// at location.
public boolean isItemAtEqual(int location, T item);

// Insert insertItem into the list at position location.
public void insertAt(int location, T insertItem);

// Insert insertItem at the end of the list.
public void insertEnd(T insertItem);

// Remove the item from the list at position location.
public void removeAt(int location);

// Retrieve the element from the list at position location,
// and return it.
public T retrieveAt(int location);

// Replace the element in the list at position location with repItem.
public void replaceAt(int location, T repItem);

// Remove all elements from the list.
public void clearList();

// Determine whether searchItem is in the list or not.  Return its
// location, or -1.
public int seqSearch(T searchItem);

// Remove item removeItem from the list.
public void remove(T removeItem);
}
```

ArrayListClass:

```
// Generic abstract ArrayList class.
// Implements ArrayListADT, so either defines or declares every method in ArrayListADT.
// Defines those methods that are generic enough to be defined.
// Left others as just abstract declarations.
// Since this class is abstract, it cannot be instantiated, but it can be declared as a reference,
// and can be used as a superclass.

public abstract class ArrayListClass<T> implements ArrayListADT<T>, Cloneable
{
// Protected member variables, inherited by any subclasses.

// The length and maximum size of the list.
protected int length;
protected int maxSize;

// The array to hold the list of any type of elements.
protected T[] list;

// Default constructor.
// Create a list size of 100, length will be 0 since it is empty.
public ArrayListClass()
{
    maxSize = 100;
    length = 0;
    list = (T[]) new Object[maxSize];
}

// Constructor.
// Create a list size of size, length will be 0 since it is empty.
public ArrayListClass(int size)
{
    // Make sure size is valid, otherwise use 100.
    if (size <= 0) 
    {
        System.err.println("The array size must be positive. Creating an array of size 100.");
        maxSize = 100;
    }
    else 
    {
        maxSize = size;
    }

    length = 0;
    list = (T[]) new Object[maxSize];
}

// Determine whether or not the list is empty.
public boolean isEmpty()
{
    // List is empty if length equals 0.
    return (length == 0);
}

// Determine whether or not the list if full.
public boolean isFull()
{
    // List is full if length equals maxSize.
    return (length == maxSize);
}

// Return the number of elements in the list.
public int listSize()
{
    return length;
}

// Return the maximum size of the list.
public int maxListSize()
{
    return maxSize;
}

// Output the elements of the list.
public void print()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        System.out.println(list[i].toString());
    }
    System.out.println();
}

// Returns a copy of objects' data in store.  
// This method clones only the references stored in the list.
// The objects themselves are not cloned.
public Object clone()
{
    // Declare a copy array to return.
    ArrayListClass<T> copy;

    // Now try to clone it.
    // First, just make a copy of the class as a whole (the 2 integers and the list).
    try
    {
        copy = (ArrayListClass<T>) super.clone();
    }
    catch (CloneNotSupportedException e)
    {
        return null;
    }

    // Now call clone on the list itself.  This will make a shallow copy of the 
    // list, though.  There is no way to make a deep copy of the list from here.
    // So right now, copy.list[0] points to the same object as list[0].
    copy.list = (T[]) list.clone();
    return copy;
}

// Determine whether item is the same as the item in the list
// at location.
public boolean isItemAtEqual(int location, T item)
{
    // Make sure location is valid.
    if (location < 0 || location >= length)
    {
        System.err.println("The location of the item to be compared is out of range.");
        return false;
    }

    // Now just return if the item at this location is equal to item.
    // Use the equals method of this Object.
    return (list[location].equals(item));
}

// Remove the item from the list at position location.
public void removeAt(int location)
{
    // Make sure location is valid.
    if (location < 0 || location >= length)
    {
        System.err.println("The location of the item to be removed is out of range.");
    }
    else
    {
        // Shift everything in the list from location to the end over one element to the left.
        // Run over what was in location, shifting the whole list over one.
        for (int i = location; i < length - 1; i++)
        {
            list[i] = list[i + 1];
        }

        // Take the last element out of the list now, we don't need it anymore (it was moved over one).
        // Reduce size by 1.
        list[length - 1] = null;
        length--;
    }
}

// Retrieve the element from the list at position location,
// and return it.
public T retrieveAt(int location)
{
    // Make sure location is valid.
    if (location < 0 || location >= length)
    {
        System.err.println("The location of the item to be retrieved is out of range.");
        return null;
    }

    // Now just return the item at that location.
    return list[location];
}

// Remove all elements from the list.
public void clearList()
{
    // Set everything in the list to null.
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        list[i] = null;
    }

    length = 0;

    // Do garbage collection to clean up all the objects out there that
    // no longer have references in the list.
    System.gc();
}

// Abstract methods, have no definition here, must be defined by subclasses.


//Search for the minimum value in the list
public abstract <T extends Comparable<T>> T minimum();

//Search for the maximum value in the list
public abstract <T extends Comparable<T>> T maximum();


// Insert insertItem into the list at position location.
public abstract void insertAt(int location, T insertItem);

// Insert insertItem at the end of the list.
public abstract void insertEnd(T insertItem);

// Replace the element in the list at position location with repItem.
public abstract void replaceAt(int location, T repItem);

// Determine whether searchItem is in the list or not.  Return its
// location, or -1.
public abstract int seqSearch(T searchItem);

// Remove item removeItem from the list.
public abstract void remove(T removeItem);
}
```

OrderedArrayList:

```
// Generic OrderedArrayList class, inherits from ArrayListClass.
// Inherits all methods from ArrayListClass, plus defines those methods that
// are abstract in ArrayListClass.
// Represents an ordered list of any type of Object.

public class OrderedArrayList<T> extends ArrayListClass<T>
{
// Default constructor.
public OrderedArrayList()
{
    super();
}

// Constructor.
public OrderedArrayList(int size)
{
    super(size);
}

// Insert insertItem into the list at the correct ordered location.
public void insert(T insertItem)
{
    int loc;
    boolean found = false;

    // Check if list is empty or full.  Insert into empty list,
    // error on full list.
    if (length == 0)
    {
        list[length++] = insertItem;
    }
    else if (length == maxSize)
    {
        System.err.println("Cannot insert in a full list.");
    }
    else
    {
        // Since the list is ordered, first find where this item needs to 
        // be inserted so the list stays ordered.
        for (loc = 0; loc < length; loc++)
        {
            Comparable<T> temp = (Comparable<T>) list[loc];
            if (temp.compareTo(insertItem) >= 0)
            {
                found = true;
                break;
            }
        }

        // If a spot for this item was not found, it must belong at the end
        // of the list.
        if (!found)
        {
            loc = length;
        }

        // Shift everything in the list from location to the end to the right,
        // to open up a new spot at location.
        for (int i = length; i > loc; i--)
        {
            list[i] = list[i - 1];
        }

        // Fill the location spot and increase length by 1.
        list[loc] = insertItem;
        length++;
    }
}

// Insert insertItem into the list at position location.
// location is actually ignored here since this list is ordered
// and the item must be inserted in its correct ordered position.
public void insertAt(int location, T insertItem)
{
    // Make sure location is valid, and that the list is not full.
    if (location < 0 || location >= maxSize)
    {
        System.err.println("The position of the item to be inserted is out of range.");
    }
    else if (length >= maxSize)
    {
        System.err.println("Cannot insert in a full list.");
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("This is a sorted list. Inserting at the proper place.");

        // Use insert method.
        insert(insertItem);
    }
}

// Insert insertItem at the end of the list.
public void insertEnd(T insertItem)
{
    if (length >= maxSize)
    {
        System.err.println("Cannot insert in a full list.");
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("This is a sorted list. Inserting at the proper place.");

        // Use insert method.
        insert(insertItem);
    }
}

// Replace the element in the list at position location with repItem.
public void replaceAt(int location, T repItem)
{
    // Make sure location is valid.
    if (location < 0 || location >= length)
    {
        System.err.println("The position of the item to be replaced is out of range.");
    }
    else
    {
        // First remove the item at this position, then insert this new
        // item in its proper ordered place.
        removeAt(location);
        insert(repItem);
    }
}

// Determine whether searchItem is in the list or not.  Return its
// location, or -1.
public int seqSearch(T searchItem)
{
    int loc;
    boolean found = false;

    // Walk through the entire list from beginning to end, looking
    // for an item in the list that is >= searchItem, because the 
    // list is ordered.  Once an item > searchItem is found, stop
    // searching.   
    for (loc = 0; loc < length; loc++)
    {
        // If searchItem is found at that location, break out of this
        // search loop.
        // Use compareTo method to compare two objects in the list, so 
        // cast them as Comparable first.           
        Comparable<T> temp = (Comparable<T>) list[loc];
        if (temp.compareTo(searchItem) >= 0)
        {
            found = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    // If found is true above in the loop, that just means the search stopped.
    // Now see if a match was actually found.
    // Otherwise return -1.
    if (found)
    {
        if (list[loc].equals(searchItem))
        {
            return loc;
        }
        else
        {
            return -1;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        return -1;
    }
}

// Remove item removeItem from the list.
public void remove(T removeItem)
{
    int loc;

    // Make sure the list has items in it.
    if (length == 0)
    {
        System.err.println("Cannot delete from an empty list.");
    }
    else
    {
        // Use seqSearch method to try to find this item first.
        loc = seqSearch(removeItem);

        // If found, use removeAt method to just remove it.
        // Otherwise, print an error, this item is not in the list.
        if (loc != -1)
        {
            removeAt(loc);
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("The item to be deleted is not in the list.");
        }
    }
}

@Override
public <T extends Comparable<T>> T minimum() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

@Override
public <T extends Comparable<T>> T maximum() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}
}
```

Comment: Can you elaborate just how your program is not working right? Your current explanations seem to me to assume that we know what your code is doing. Also better if you can create and post a [minimal code example program](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Why are you implementing a list?  Have you considered just sorting your list with [Arrays.sort()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort%28T[],%20java.util.Comparator%29) and then using a [Array.binarySearch()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#binarySearch%28T[],%20T,%20java.util.Comparator%29) to get the index where you want to insert?

Comment: @user3294343: I'm guessing that this is homework.

Answer (score 1):

You're creating a completely new JList inside of your actionPerformed method and adding data to it, which will have no effect on the completely separate displayed JList. Suggestion: don't create a new JList object. Instead use the JList, or better its model, that you have.

Better would be to create your own custom ListModel based on the AbstractListModel, and make your `ArrayListClass<T>` or the interface the *nucleus* of this model. Then make sure to make all data changes through this model class.